# Why is the array operation performance in Swift slower?

Tags: swift, performance

When I try to solve the problem in [Leetcode 1208](https://leetcode.com/problems/get-equal-substrings-within-budget/) I notice the Swift code is much slower than Objective-C.

Here is my code in Swift:

```swift
func equalSubstring(_ s: String, _ t: String, _ maxCost: Int) -> Int {
    let list = zip(s,t).map { $0 }
    var costList = [Int].init(repeating: 0, count: list.count)
    for item in list.enumerated() {
        costList[item.offset] = abs(Int(item.element.0.asciiValue!) - Int(item.element.1.asciiValue!))
    }

    var maxLen = 0
    for i in 0..<costList.count {
        var len = 0, cost = maxCost
        for j in i..<costList.count {
            cost -= costList[j]
            if cost >= 0 {
                len += 1
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        if len > maxLen {
            maxLen = len
        }
    }

    return maxLen
}
```

It takes 496.363 seconds to deal with the 100000 length input with maxCost 93020. [Test case](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/267153623/testcase/)

But if I use same approach in Objective-C it takes only 19s:

```c
- (int)equalSubstring:(NSString *)s t:(NSString *)t maxCost:(int)maxCost {
    NSMutableArray *costList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
        [costList addObject:@(abs([s characterAtIndex:i] - [t characterAtIndex:i]))];
    }

    int maxLen = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<costList.count; i++) {
        int cost = maxCost, len = 0;
        for (int j=i; j<costList.count; j++) {
            cost -= [costList[j] intValue];
            if (cost >= 0) {
                len += 1;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (len > maxLen) {
            maxLen = len;
        }
    }

    return maxLen;
}
```

in Javascript will be even faster:

```js
var equalSubstring = function(s, t, maxCost) {

    var maxLength = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
        var cost = maxCost, len = 0;
        for (var j=i; j<s.length; j++) {
            let c = Math.abs(s.charCodeAt(j) - t.charCodeAt(j));
            cost -= c;
            if (cost >= 0) {
                len += 1;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (len > maxLength) {
            maxLength = len;
        }
    }

    return maxLength;
};
```

What could be the reason make Swift so slow? Will the problem be the language itself?

Comment: Are you testing in an optimized build for a command line app or are you testing in the playground?

Comment: Thats really weird, if you turn on optimisation its really quick, on my machine a second, but without the optimisation I gave up on it, a similar thing happens if you run it in the profiler, it really quick. You could try raising a bug with Apple, but it might be just the cost of not having optimisation, if you want all the benefits of being able to debug your code it's going to be slower, but the difference does seem a bit extreme.

Comment: Hi Ramddy, I tested on playground also in unit test class without the optimized.

Comment: Hi Nathan, I am test with -Ofast and -Os in Unit Test class, but it seems didn't get faster... Are you running the test on real project?

Comment: @iMax Never test performance in a playground. Only test Swift performance in a real, optimized app.